# Regex to match one or more characters

Tags: regex, string

I need to filter a set of strings with a wildcard-type search, like the following:

- Looking for `He*lo` should match "Hello", but not "Helo"
- Looking for `*ant` should match "pant" and "want" but not "ant"
- Looking for `*yp*` should match "gypsy" and "typical"

The `*` represents one or more characters. I don't mind a handwritten or regex-based search. Any ideas? The typical .NET approach for wildcards matches **0 or more**, but I need **1 or more characters.** How can I do this?

Comment: `+` means *1 or more* in regex. You can use that.

Answer (score 9):

What you're looking for is the + regex operator

Comment: `+` is not an operator, it's a *quantifier*

Comment: and quantifiers are not operators?

Comment: quantifier is a better word I guess thanks. From what I've googled though it's used interchangeably in regex literature.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `.`

For example: `he.lo` will match your `hello`, but not `helo`.

same goes for the rest.

You can easily test it here: http://regexpal.com/.

Do note that `.yp.` will not match `typical` nor `gypsy`, but `.yp.+' will (because of the rest of the characters)